# How to output an API having names different than variable names?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api, backend

I have an entity like the following

```
@Data
@NoArgsCounstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Class {
@JsonProperty("Data")
List<ClassData> classData;
}
```

I want to view this as "Data" in the output but instead, it gives "classData" as the field. I have tried a bunch of annotations but nothing seems to work. Please tell me how can I get this kind of output.

Output

```
{
"classData":[]
}
```

Required Output

```
{
"Data":[]
}
```

Edit: I am getting the field with a different name and I need to give the output with some other name. For instance I am getting input as "ClassData" and giving output as "Data"

Comment: Double check that you are using `Jackson` for serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the way to do it!

Instead of using `@JsonProperty` using `@JsonSetter` for getting the input and then `@SerializedName` for renaming the data for the output

Thank you everyone for helping

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use Jackson to serialize/deserialize your resources, simply rename the POJO field and `classData` to `data` and Jackson will use the new field name in order to create the JSON output.

Comment: Shouldnt it work already wit `@JsonProperty`?

Comment: It should given that the OP is using Jackson and that the latter has been configured correctly. However it is not clearly stated that they are using Jackson correctly.

Comment: But then what is the point of your answer. You could copy paste OPs code as well. *Assuming that you use Jackson to serialize/deserialize* well, having that assumption in mind it should already work.

Comment: As mentioned above, there is no clear indication that they are using Jackson. On top of that there is no code examples in order to review what they have on hand. Hence, with no information available, the easiest way to address their issue is simply to rename the field.